# Continuously updating a plot from a C++ program (animation?)

Tags: c++, python, plot, gnuplot

I have a C++ program that continuously update a graph (add/delete edges and vertices). Is it possible to plot the manipulated graph using gnuplot ([using arrow command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104378/plot-points-linked-with-edges-using-gnuplot)) from my C++ program and update the plot each time the graph is updated ? This is a sort of animation ...

Comment: Have you checked if GNUplot has an API you could call from your C++  program?

Comment: I don't know much about calling gnuplot from C++, but try looking into the `-persist` command line flag to gnuplot (this will keep displaying a plot until you close it instead of drawing it and exiting) and the `replot` command in gnuplot.

Comment: Are you on Linux or other Unix? If so and if you program|gnuplot can be got to work, then you can set up the pipe from within you program. Using pipe,fork,exec have a look here http://richarddelorenzi.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/creation-of-an-interprocess-pipe/

Comment: @richard I'm on windows.

Comment: OK, are you trying to do the equivalent of 'my_sub_program | gnuplot' ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181512/pipe-fork-and-execvp-analogs-in-windows is an question and answer about setting up an interprocess pipe in ms-windows.

Comment: @richard Well this seems complicated. Is there any other easier way to do this animation ?

Comment: Seems like there is a C++ API for gnuplot here http://www.suiri.tsukuba.ac.jp/~asanuma/gnuplot++/  but I don't know how to do the animation as I explained

Comment: I would write a class that implements Cout and/or printf, has a constructor that launches another program connected to its stdin, and a close routine/destructor that closes the stream and other program. Then use it and drop it in my tool box for latter use. (or even ask some one to write this class for you). It is easy if you already have my_prog | there_prog but want to put the pipe set up in my_prog (integrate them).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using pipe commands, should also work on Windows according to this:
http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.dk/2009/05/how-to-call-gnuplot-from-c-using-pipes.html

An example (this one's using POSIX and mouse, so you may want to adapt the above example instead):
http://www.gnuplot.info/files/gpReadMouseTest.c

As an alternative, consider using MathGL: http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/mathgl_en.html